# Dropdown com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, front-end

Estou trabalhando em um projeto e me deparei com a seguinte situação: uma lista de itens para uma barra de navegação lateral precisa de botões que se fechem e que abram ao click (até aí beleza). No entanto preciso entender como faço para que quando um seja aberto, os outros que já foram abertos se fechem.

```
<body>
    <nav class="side-navbar">
        <div>
            <a href="#" class="main" id="titulo1">Titulo1</a>
            <ul class="lista">
                    <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div>
            <a href="#" class="main" id="titulo2">Titulo2</a>
            <ul class="lista">
                    <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item4</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="#" class="main" id="titulo3">Titulo3</a>
            <ul class="lista">
                    <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item4</a></li>
            </ul>
       </div>
    </nav>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

#### CSS

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: none;
}

.main{
    font-size: 22px;
    display: block;
}

.toggle{
    display: block;
}

.untuggle{
    display: none;
}
```

#### JS

```
let main = document.querySelectorAll('.main');
let itens = document.querySelectorAll('.lista');

function toggleSide(togle, untugle){
    for(let i = 0; i < main.length; i++){
        main[i].addEventListener('click', function(){

        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara a forma como vc montou o script e o CSS não está legal. Fiz esse modelo simplificado que acho que vai te ajudar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Funciona assim, quando vc clica no `link` vc adiciona a classe ativo nele, e no css vc define que `link.ativo + .list {display:block}`. Assim sempre que tiver um `link` com classe .ativo a lista que vier abaixo fica com `display:block`

Depois disso vc tem que tirar as classes dos elementos, para isso eu fiz um `forEach()`, dentro da função que adiciona a classe .ativo, esse `forEach()` primeiro remove a classe .ativo de todo mundo, e na sequencia eu adiciona a classe .ativo apenas no elemento clicado com `e.currentTarget.classList.add('ativo');`

Segue o código

```js
var link = document.querySelectorAll('.main');

function classe(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    link.forEach( (rmk) => {
        rmk.classList.remove('ativo');
    })
    e.currentTarget.classList.add('ativo');
}

link.forEach( (el) => {
    el.addEventListener('click', classe);
})
```

```css
.lista {
    list-style: none;
    display: none;
}

.main {
    font-size: 22px;
    display: block;
}
.main.ativo + .lista {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="side-navbar">
    <div>
        <a href="#" class="main" id="titulo1">Titulo1</a>
        <ul class="lista">
            <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div>
        <a href="#" class="main" id="titulo2">Titulo2</a>
        <ul class="lista">
            <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#" class="main" id="titulo3">Titulo3</a>
        <ul class="lista">
            <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const main = document.querySelectorAll('.main');
const lista = document.querySelectorAll('.lista');

main.forEach(function(el, i) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
  
    lista.forEach(function(el2, i2) {
      el2.style.display = 'none';
    });
    
    this.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
}

.main {
  font-size: 22px;
  display: block;
}

.toggle {
  display: block;
}

.untuggle {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="side-navbar">
  <div>
    <a href="#" class="main" id="titulo1">Titulo1</a>
    <ul class="lista">
      <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div>
    <a href="#" class="main" id="titulo2">Titulo2</a>
    <ul class="lista">
      <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">item4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="#" class="main" id="titulo3">Titulo3</a>
    <ul class="lista">
      <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">item4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você nem precisa da classe `.untuggle`. Se os elementos já são *invisíveis* com `ul display: none`, basta adicionar/remover a classe `.toggle`.

Ao clicar em um item, aquele menu é aberto e outro que tiver aberto é fechado. Se o item estiver aberto e clicar novamente nele, ele é fechado.

Veja no exemplo abaixo como fazer isso com JavaScript (comentários explicativos no código):

```js
let main = document.querySelectorAll('.main');

for(let i = 0; i < main.length; i++){
   main[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
      
      // busca algum elemento que possua a classe .toggle
      let aberto = document.querySelector(".toggle");
      
      // pega o elemento posterior ao item clicado (ul)
      let lista = this.nextElementSibling;

      // verifica se existe algum elemento com a classe .toggle
      // e que não seja o elemento posterior ao item clicado
      if(aberto && aberto != lista){
         aberto.classList.remove("toggle");
      }
      
      // verifica de a UL possui a classe .toggle
      if(~lista.className.indexOf("toggle")){
         // se possuir, remove a classe
         lista.classList.remove("toggle");
      }else{
         // se não possuir, adiciona a classe
         lista.classList.add("toggle");
      }
   });
}
```

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: none;
}

.main{
    font-size: 22px;
    display: block;
}

.toggle{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="side-navbar">
        <div>
            <a href="#" class="main" id="titulo1">Titulo1</a>
            <ul class="lista">
                    <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div>
            <a href="#" class="main" id="titulo2">Titulo2</a>
            <ul class="lista">
                    <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item4</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="#" class="main" id="titulo3">Titulo3</a>
            <ul class="lista">
                    <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item4</a></li>
            </ul>
       </div>
    </nav>
```

Abaixo o código um pouco mais *enxuto*:

```
let main = document.querySelectorAll('.main');
for(let item of main){
   item.addEventListener('click', function(){
      let aberto = document.querySelector(".toggle");
      let lista = this.nextElementSibling;
      if(aberto && aberto != lista) aberto.classList.remove("toggle");
      lista.classList[~lista.className.indexOf("toggle") ? "remove" : "add"]("toggle");
   });
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Não faça um FOR, usa classe CSS e muda a classe CSS pelo Javascript.

Daí vc cria duas classes "listaaberta" "listafechada" daí ao clicar em um, vc pede troca usando document.getElementsByClass('listaaberta') e muda para fechada.

Isso é bem fácil se vc usar jQuery